# Likelihood of a document-term matrix

Tags: modeling, maximum-likelihood, latent-variable

I'm trying to deeply understand the [Probabilistic Latent Semantic Indexing (PLSI)](http://cs.brown.edu/~th/papers/Hofmann-SIGIR99.pdf) algorithm.

The generative model underlying the algorithm is the folowing:

1. Select a document $d \in D$ with a probability $P(d)$
2. Select a topic $t \in T$ with probability $P(t|d)$
3. Generate a word $w \in W$ with a probability $P(w|t)$

where the sets $D$, $T$ and $W$ are finite and fixed and all the probability distributions are multinomial.

Given an observation, which is a corpus $C$ of documents, the author computes the likelihood function as:
$$L = \prod_{d\in D}\prod_{w \in W} n(d,w) p(d)\sum_{t \in T} p(w|t)p(t|d)$$

where $n(d,w)$ is the number of occurrences of the term $w$ within the document $d$.

My question is: given that we are not considering the order of the words within a document, shouldn't we consider, for each document, also the *multinomial coefficient* ?
$$ C_d = \binom{\sum_{w}{n(d,w)}}{n(d,w_1), n(d,w_2), \dots , nd(w_W)}$$

Could you explain me why it has been omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you include it, it's irrelevant. It would cancel out between the numerator and denominator when you apply Bayes' theorem and you'd be left with the same posterior equation given in the paper. I haven't read into this enough to determine whether the multinomial is really necessary in this likelihood function, but it's pretty common practice for Bayesians to ignore scaling terms like this since they cancel out anyway.

To demonstrate, consider the following model:

- Prior: $p(\theta_i)$
- Likelihood: $k*p(X|\theta_i)$ (where $k$ is a scaling term made explicit for this demonstration)

Then applying Bayes rule gives:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p(\theta_i|X)& = \frac{k*p(X|\theta_i)p(\theta_i)}{ \sum_{\theta} k*p(X|\theta)p(\theta) } \\
& = \frac{k*p(X|\theta_i)p(\theta_i)}{ k*\sum_{\theta} p(X|\theta)p(\theta) } \\
& = \frac{p(X|\theta_i)p(\theta_i)}{\sum_{\theta} p(X|\theta)p(\theta) }
\end{split}
\end{equation}